# WebView and setInitialScale = ugly text reflow

Tags: android, webview

I'm using WebView control to load html from a file using WebView.loadUrl.
Before that call, I set initial scale by WebView.setInitialScale to value which is less than 100% (e.g. 30%).

All works fine, except there's visual glitch, and probably waste of CPU time, when page first displays narrow, as if computed with 100% scale, then reflows to fill screen width.
Pause is about 1 second in case of screenshots below.

I see no way how to avoid this ugly and useless display of narrow text.
Anyone has experience how to get around this?

[image: First phase shown for ~1 second]  [image: Second phase shown afterwards]

Comment: Not sure of the problem. Try using `setWillnotCacheDrawing(true)`.

Comment: how about setting it to false. Dont know the default value.

Comment: try this `setRenderPriority(WebSettings.RenderPriority.HIGH)` of the `WebSettings` class.

Comment: No help with setRenderPriority.